# Find and return a word in a sentence in SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a column in my SQLite database which contains a long string. For example:

```
This is almost a long sentence in the column I have mentioned!
```

I want to pass some letters of a word and get the entire word, not the sentence itself! For example, I want to enter `sen` and get the word `sentence`.

I'm looking for a way to execute an SQL query to do so, is there any solution?

Comment: Use `instr(X,Y) ` and `substr(X,Y,Z)`: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html

Comment: I think this post can help you
http://www.sqlteam.com/article/returning-complete-words-from-a-substring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select substr(substr(f, instr(f, "sen")),             -- starting with 'sen'
              0,
              instr(substr(f, instr(f, "sen")), " ")) -- ending with space
  from t;
```

Comment: It doesn't work the way I want. Sometimes it returns some words that don't have 'sen' in them!

Comment: Just added a LIKE command at the end of the query and it works! Thank you so much!